# How to resolve Legends formatting Issue in SSRS pie Chart

Tags: reporting-services, pie-chart

I am using SSRS reporting. I have designed a report which contains some Pie Chart.
All the things working fine. There is some issue around the Legends alignment and font family .
If you see attached image. You will see the 1st Pie charts legends are different than 2nd pie Chart's Legends.
I have set same properties for both pie Chart's Legends.

Can any body suggest the solutions regarding this issue. 
[image: SSRS Issue with Legends]

Thanks in advance
Ashish Bisht

Comment: While I appreciate that they are different, what are they supposed to show?  I note that the first item Anchor store has the prefix 66 and 151.  What is this and are either of them correct?  Is this figure being determined by a query.  Also, are you concerned about the layout of the legend, or the data itself?

Comment: Just the layout of Legends. Data may Number may vary but the Legends name will be same. Data Set is same for both Graph only difference is for the field which we are using for Pie Chart Area.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give same size to both the pie charts, if layout of Lengends is not matching and check if this resolves your problem.

Try to give same size to the chart area of both the charts (Select Chart Area, F4, in the properties window look for Custome Position, Set Enabled to TRUE, give Height, Width, Left, Right ). Check if this gives same size to your chart area.

If you are trying to have same legend text value, then try this,
Right click on Series (in char data box) ---> Series Properties --> Legend -- > Custome Legen Text .. Here you give the text you want to see in your Legend.

Try the three possibilities, hope any one of the three resolves your problem.

Comment: I have made changes as per your suggestion. None of them works for me.
Will there any Data source related issue?

Comment: From the image you have provided, I thought it could be because of Chart Area Size mismatch. Can you please tell what exactly  you mean, when you say Legend Layout Issue ?

Comment: I have a datasource which has three fields 
1-Sector name
2-PreviousYearCount
3-CurrentYearCount
First Graph has CurrentYearCount as Category Field and Sectorname in series and For Second Graph PreviousYearCount and Sectorname.

I have set the Layout as per the Second Graph in both Graphs but when we view reports in Reports viewer its show the misalignment as per attached Image.

Comment: I thought adjusting Chart Area properties, not Chart Properties, would solve your problem but it seems some thing else.